# Synchronize BCS when item is deleted from source

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, external-data

I have a contact list where i store all my contacts info.
In my subsites, I have lists where i created an External Data Column which is referenced to the Contact list.

The Problem is : When i delete or change some info in the contact list, it's not synchronized automatically in the other lists.

How i can do that using Powershell may be? or if you have another solution please?

Comment: Please share the external content type setting, maybe it has configured as one way!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Mohamed You mean this? what's the settings required to do that?